# Principal bundle associated to a Courant algebroid

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, fibre-bundles

A Courant algebroid is defined as a real vector bundle equipped with a product and a symmetric bilinear on its space of sections satisfying a particular set of conditions. What would be the definition of a Courant algebroid on the associated principal bundle? In other words, what is the structure that a principal bundle must have in order for the associated vector bundle to be a Courant algebroid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the bracket (you call it product) is a bidifferential operator on the space of sections of the vector bundle, the translation to the principal bundles is not straightforward. You have to use the first jet bundle of a principal bundle and to associate to it the jet bundle of the associated vector bundle. Bilinearity has to be linearized by using the tensor-product (of the space of sections), etc.
This works like a bilinear extension of lifting a connection to a principal bundle.

Comment: A simpler question, to begin understanding the situation: how is characterized the space of sections of a vector bundle on the associated principal bundle?

Comment: See 18.12 of http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/dgbook.pdf

Comment: I fail to find now the answer in your book (which is very nice by the way), but I guess that if a section of rank-$n$ vector bundle $E$ is an equivariant function on the associated principal bundle $F(E)$ taking values in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then the space of sections in $E$ corresponds to the space of equivariant functions on $F(E)$ taking values in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Edit: I mistake the section that you mentioned and that is why I didn't find it; it is indeed clearly explained in the first theorem of section 18.12.